# trying to colorize a simple PNG and draw inside a mask element in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, png, pixel, composite

I tried to create an HTML canvas, place a rectangle... then INSIDE THAT rectangle, draw various shapes and an RGBa PNG... all of them clipped inside the dimensions of the rectangle. Then I tried to change the color of the PNG when you press an HTML button input. (Further comments in code.)

Heres the problems... A. You have to draw to a temporary canvas and apply "GlobalCompositeOperation source-atop" just AFTER the clipping rectangle. Everything drawn after that is successfully clipped into the rect shape. Then the whole thing is copied (drawn) to a MAIN canvas. I was told to do it this way in order for the programming to recognize MULTIPLE elements after a "composite" operation. I have to say this works BEAUTIFULLY!! but here's problem B...

To to a "getData" on an image (to change color), I think you have to place the image on a canvas, and doing all the image pixel manipulation screws up the "composite" operation, so I tried to draw the PNG to a THIRD canvas, do the pixel changes, and then draw it to the temporary canvas... adding it to the rest of the elements....THEEENNN draw it all to the main canvas. Does not work. See code. Please help, Im mad enough to chew neutronium.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="theCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:2px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<canvas id="tempCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="display:none;"></canvas>
<canvas id="anotherCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="display:none;"></canvas>
<form>
<input type="button" id="changeColor" value="Click to Change Color of Graphic">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hereWeGoAgain_GHELP.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
//------------------------------------- JS
window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);

function eventWindowLoaded () {
    canvasApp();
}
function canvasApp() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('theCanvas');// the main canvas, where it all goes in the end
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var tempCanvas = document.getElementById('tempCanvas');// the canvas to do my "source-atop" stuff...
    var tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');

    var anotherCanvas = document.getElementById('anotherCanvas');
    var anotherContext = anotherCanvas.getContext('2d');

// ...and Im thinking I should draw the RGBA PNG here, before placing it in the temp canvas, with the other elements

    var cc = document.getElementById('changeColor');
    cc.addEventListener('click', function(){changeColorFunction('ff0000');}, false);
// the HTML form button to change the PNG color

    var colorOfThePlacedPNG = "#000000";
    var imagesToLoad = 0;
    var imagesLoaded = 0;

    function drawScreen() {

        tempContext.fillStyle="#999999";
        tempContext.fillRect(0,0,200,200); //color the whole temp canvas area grey....
        tempContext.fillStyle="#2baae1";
        tempContext.fillRect(30,30,140,140);//now draw a light blue rect inside....

        tempContext.globalCompositeOperation="source-atop"; // now make everything drawn AFTERWARDS be clipped (masked) inside the blue rect

// when I comment out the above "global Comp Op"... everything draws to the main canvas normally...just not clipped(masked) however

        tempContext.fillStyle="#f47e1f";
        tempContext.fillRect(150,100,150,150);//SO heres an orange box intentionally clipped off the bottom right in the blue rect
        tempContext.fillStyle="#d89bc5";
        tempContext.fillRect(40,50,80,200);//AND heres a light purple rect intentionally clipped at the bottom of the blue rect

        getTheImageData(); //draw PNG to another canvas, convert image data, put in tempContext

        //tempContext.restore();//dont know if I need this
        context.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);// and then FINALLY draw all to the main canvas
        }
        var loaded = function(){
            imagesLoaded += 1;
            if(imagesLoaded === imagesToLoad){ 
                drawScreen();
            }
        }
    var loadImage = function(url){
            var image = new Image();   
            image.addEventListener("load",loaded);
            imagesToLoad += 1;
            image.src = url;
            return image;
            }
    function changeColorFunction(e) {
            colorOfThePlacedPNG = e;
            drawScreen();
    }
    function getTheImageData(){
        anotherContext.drawImage(testPNGimage, 0, 0);// draw to the third canvas(another canvas)
            var imgData = anotherContext.getImageData(0, 0, 200, 200);
                    // how do i color it red? ....like #ff0000 ???
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
                imgData.data[i] = 255 - imgData.data[i];
                imgData.data[i+1] = 255 - imgData.data[i+1];
                imgData.data[i+2] = 255 - imgData.data[i+2];
                imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
            }
            tempContext.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
    }
        var testPNGimage = loadImage("test.png");// the PNG is just a 75X75px black squiggle drawn in pshop
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things!

**There is a clipping method built into canvas.**

Use clipping instead of compositing and multiple canvases.

Do this and all new drawings will be clipped inside your 140x140 rect:

```
context.beginPath();
context.rect(30,30,140,140);
context.clip();
```

**Here's a simplified redesign of your code:**

1. Draw a grey rect filling the canvas.
2. Draw a blue 140x140 rect at [30,30].
3. Clip all new drawings into the blue rect with `context.clip()`
4. Draw a clipped orange rect.
5. Draw a clipped purple rect.
6. Unclip so new drawings will be visible anywhere on the canvas.
7. Draw the squiggle image (it's not clipped).
8. Use `.getImageData` to invert every pixel's color.

**And a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/squiggle.png";
function start(){

  //color the whole canvas area grey....
  ctx.fillStyle="#999999";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,200); 

  //now draw a light blue rect inside....
  ctx.fillStyle="#2baae1";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(30,30,140,140);
  ctx.fill();

  // save the unclipped context state
  ctx.save();

  // cause all new drawings to be clipped inside
  // the blue 140x140 rect at [30,30]
  ctx.clip();

  //SO heres an orange box intentionally clipped off the bottom right in the blue rect
  ctx.fillStyle="#f47e1f";
  ctx.fillRect(150,100,150,150);

  //AND heres a light purple rect intentionally clipped at the bottom of the blue rect
  ctx.fillStyle="#d89bc5";
  ctx.fillRect(40,50,80,200);

  // restore the context state (releases clipping for new drawings)
  ctx.restore();

  // draw the squiggley line image -- it's not clipped in the blue rect
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  // invert the colors using getImageData
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 200, 200);
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imgData.data[i] = 255 - imgData.data[i];
    imgData.data[i+1] = 255 - imgData.data[i+1];
    imgData.data[i+2] = 255 - imgData.data[i+2];
    imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: How to isolate the image... do the color changes on it.. then draw it to the canvas with the rest of the elements? Thank you @markE

Comment: @bobcodenewbie. You can fetch just the image pixels by limiting .getImageData to just the area of the image: `ctx.getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height)` Then process those pixels and put them back with `.putImageData(0,0)`.